# Is there a Bitcoin mining library?

Tags: library

I write free software in my spare time. Some of my softwares are quite popular. Now i'm a thinking of a way to generate a little revenue. Using adware is not an option for me.

Is there a Bitcoin mining library ( maybe a .dll ) that i can bundle into my programs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to mine bitcoin on home PCs will generate you absolutely no income, to mine bitcoin you need a lot of hashpower which home PCs just don't have. So that isn't a viable way to generate revenue. But also, secretly mining bitcoin on peoples computers while they run your software is probably quite dishonest, if you tried such a thing you would need to ensure you let them know it was going to happen. And antivirus software would probably quarantine your file as a bitcoin mining trojan.

Comment: I wouldn't do it secretly and i'm aware about possible issues with antivirus softwares.
Would it be profitable enough (0.5 - 1 BC per year) when 10.000 PC users mine for 20 minutes per day?

Comment: Honestly you'd be lucky to make even $5 in a year, mining pools probably won't even pay out such low amounts that you'd be generating I'm afraid